# UNIQUE and OR in one SQL Server constraint?

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints, ssms

I have a table where I want a constraint that checks the following (letters are column names, W is a 'bit' datatype):

```
If and only if 'W' = 0, check that X, Y & Z are unique.
Else, allow all new data.
```

I can do the `'W' is False` and the `Check X, Y & Z are unique` separately, but merging the logic to allow for the above is what I can't figure out.

I tried

```
W = 1 OR UNIQUE (X, Y, Z)
```

but SSMS is saying that it's invalid.

Help is appreciated in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do that through a constraint.  Instead, use a filtered unique index:

```
create unique index unq_x_w on t(x) where w = 0;
create unique index unq_y_w on t(y) where w = 0;
create unique index unq_z_w on t(z) where w = 0;
```

Actually, the above interprets your question as each column is unique.  If you want the triple to be unique:

```
create unique index unq_xyz_w on t(x, y, z) where w = 0;
```